# Spark: I see more executors than available cluster's cores

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight, executor

I'm working with Spark and Yarn on an Azure HDInsight cluster, and I have some troubles on understanding the relations between the workers' resources, executors and containers.

My cluster has 10 workers D13 v2 (8 cores and 56GB of memery), therefore I should have 80 cores available for spark applications. However, when I try to start an application with the following parameters

```
"executorMemory": "6G",
"executorCores": 5,
"numExecutors": 20,
```

I see in the Yarn UI 100 cores available (therefore, 20 more than what I should have). I've run an heavy query, and on the executor page of Yarn UI I see all 20 executors working, with 4 or 5 active task in parallel. I tried also pushing the numExecutors to 25, and I do see all 25 working, again with several tasks in parallel for each executor.

It was my understanding the 1 executor core = 1 cluster core, but this is not compatible with what I observe. The official Microsoft documentation (for instance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-settings)) it's not really helpful. It states:

> An Executor runs on the worker node and is responsible for the tasks
> for the application. The number of worker nodes and worker node size
> determines the number of executors, and executor sizes.

but it does not say what the relation is. I suspect Yarn is only bound by memory limits (e.g. I can run how many executors I want, if I have enough memory), but I don't understand how this might work in relation with the available cpus in the cluster.

Do you know what I am missing?